# Trying to connect to Derby Database using OpenJPA in a Maven project, but getting a "java.sql.SQLException" error.

Tags: java, maven, jpa, jdbc, openjpa

So I did `sudo apt-get install sun-javadb-client sun-javadb-core`. Added `javadb/bin` to `PATH` and exported `DERBY_HOME`. Then I created the database by doing `CONNECT 'jdbc:derby:/home/ijk/MyDbTest;create=true';` using `ij`. [I used this tutorial for the first part](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/derby-javadb/). So `dblook` gives

```
ijk@ubuntuvm:~$ dblook -d 'jdbc:derby:/home/ijk/MyDbTest'
-- Timestamp: 2014-06-27 18:32:11.933
-- Source database is: /home/ijk/MyDbTest
-- Connection URL is: jdbc:derby:/home/ijk/MyDbTest
-- appendLogs: false
```

Now I have a Maven project with the following pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.groupdo</groupId>
<artifactId>server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>server</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
        <artifactId>openjpa-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
        <version>10.10.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Here is one Entity class which I am trying to work with:

```
package com.groupdo.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Here is the `persistence.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="testjpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>
            org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
        </provider>
        <class>entity.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:derby:/home/ijk/MyDbTest;create=true" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="admin" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="admin" />
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=TRACE" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And here is the class which I am trying to test my set up with:

```
package com.groupdo.server;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import com.groupdo.models.User;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testjpa");
        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction userTransaction = em.getTransaction();

        userTransaction.begin();
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("alex");
        user.setPassword("pass");
        em.persist(user);
        userTransaction.commit();
        em.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }

}
```

I am getting the following stack trace and don't know what's wrong:

```
503  testjpa  INFO   [main] openjpa.Runtime - OpenJPA dynamically loaded the class enhancer. Any classes that were not enhanced at build time will be enhanced when they are loaded by the JVM.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
659  testjpa  INFO   [main] openjpa.Runtime - OpenJPA dynamically loaded a validation provider.
686  testjpa  INFO   [main] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 2.3.0
722  testjpa  INFO   [main] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DerbyDictionary".
Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There were errors initializing your configuration: <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.UserException: A connection could not be obtained for driver class "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" and URL "jdbc:derby:/home/ijk/MyDbTest;create=true".  You may have specified an invalid URL.
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.newConnectException(DataSourceFactory.java:255)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.installDBDictionary(DataSourceFactory.java:241)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getConnectionFactory(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:733)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ConfigurationImpl.instantiateAll(ConfigurationImpl.java:310)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.instantiateAll(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:1670)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.makeReadOnly(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:651)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:203)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:59)
    at com.groupdo.server.Test.main(Test.java:14)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:derby:/home/ijk/MyDbTest;create=true'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DBCPDriverDataSource.getDBCPConnection(DBCPDriverDataSource.java:74)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.AutoDriverDataSource.getConnection(AutoDriverDataSource.java:42)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SimpleDriverDataSource.getConnection(SimpleDriverDataSource.java:76)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingDataSource.getConnection(DelegatingDataSource.java:118)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DecoratingDataSource.getConnection(DecoratingDataSource.java:93)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.installDBDictionary(DataSourceFactory.java:233)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:278)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    ... 22 more

    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:218)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:59)
    at com.groupdo.server.Test.main(Test.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There were errors initializing your configuration: <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.UserException: A connection could not be obtained for driver class "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" and URL "jdbc:derby:/home/ijk/MyDbTest;create=true".  You may have specified an invalid URL.
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.newConnectException(DataSourceFactory.java:255)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.installDBDictionary(DataSourceFactory.java:241)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getConnectionFactory(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:733)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ConfigurationImpl.instantiateAll(ConfigurationImpl.java:310)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.instantiateAll(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:1670)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.makeReadOnly(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:651)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:203)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:59)
    at com.groupdo.server.Test.main(Test.java:14)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:derby:/home/ijk/MyDbTest;create=true'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DBCPDriverDataSource.getDBCPConnection(DBCPDriverDataSource.java:74)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.AutoDriverDataSource.getConnection(AutoDriverDataSource.java:42)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SimpleDriverDataSource.getConnection(SimpleDriverDataSource.java:76)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingDataSource.getConnection(DelegatingDataSource.java:118)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DecoratingDataSource.getConnection(DecoratingDataSource.java:93)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.installDBDictionary(DataSourceFactory.java:233)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:278)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    ... 22 more

    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ConfigurationImpl.instantiateAll(ConfigurationImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.instantiateAll(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:1670)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.makeReadOnly(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:651)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:203)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `<property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />` to `<property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />` (and the corresponding Maven dependency) and got past this problem onto a new problem (of Entity enhancement).